# Using nested lists in dplyr filter() raises error

Tags: r, debugging, dplyr

If I access nested elements in a list with the `$` operator with `dplyr::filter()` I get this error:

> Error: invalid subscript type 'closure'

The error is not triggered if `[]` are used.

Here's some dummy code:

```
d <- data.frame(days = seq(ymd('2017/1/1'), ymd('2017/2/1'), by = 'days'))

test <- list(
    period = list(start = ymd('2017/1/10')
    )
)

d %>% filter(days > probe$period$start)
## Here's the error

d %>% filter(days > probe$period['start'])
## This works!
```

Comment: what is `probe`

Comment: Seems like a bug that should already have been fixed: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2125

Comment: so should I open an issue there?

Comment: You probably should